# Serving remote static files with symfony3

Tags: nginx, symfony, fastcgi, nginx-location

I have a problem with my Nginx configuration. I have 2 servers, one with nginx and one with my webApp in symfony3. 
Here is my configuration :

```
location /portal/mysite/ {

    set $frontRoot /srv/data/apps/mysite-portal-stag/current/web;
    set $sfApp app.php; # Change to app.php for prod or app_dev.php for dev

    root  /srv/data/apps/mysite-portal-stag/current/web;

    rewrite ^/portal/mysite/(.*)$ /$1 break; 
    try_files $uri @sfFront;

}
location @sfFront {

    root  /srv/data/apps/mysite-portal-stag/current/web;

    fastcgi_pass myserver:myport;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $frontRoot/$sfApp;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /portal/mysite/$sfApp;

}
```

The webSite work for all the php scripts but all the assets (static files) are broken files. I don't understand enough how Nginx works to indicate what are the static files and "tell" my proxy that they aren't script.

Comment: Try changing `include fastcgi_params` to `include fastcgi.conf` and remove the `fastcgi_param`s you've set. Instead, add `fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;`. In my opinion, the paths you're passing are probably wrong which is why things work partially. I have `php-fpm` and `nginx` with reverse proxy and it works just fine.

Comment: @JeanDoux, I hope you find my answer useful and keep your part of the bounty bargain; else, feel free to let me know if anything was unclear, and i'd be happy to connect the leftover dots, if any.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `try_files` directive automatically tries to find static files, and serve them as static, prior to giving up, and letting the request be served as a script.

- http://nginx.org/r/try_files

  > Checks the existence of files in the specified order and uses the first found file for request processing; the processing is performed in the current context. The path to a file is constructed from the file parameter according to the root and alias directives. It is possible to check directory’s existence by specifying a slash at the end of a name, e.g. “$uri/”. If none of the files were found, an internal redirect to the uri specified in the last parameter is made.

Note that although you're already using `try_files`, it appears that perhaps your path handling isn't up to spec.

---

As for your own answer with a temporary solution, [there's nothing wrong with using a rewrite or two](http://mdoc.su/), but that said, it looks like you'd benefit from the `alias` directive.

- http://nginx.org/r/alias

  > Defines a replacement for the specified location.

However, you've never explained why you're serving stuff out of `/tmp`.  Note that `/tmp` is often automatically cleared by some [`cron`](http://mdoc.su/o/cron.8) scripts, e.g., on OpenBSD, the [`/etc/daily`](http://bxr.su/OpenBSD/etc/daily) script would automatically [`find`](http://mdoc.su/o/find.1) and remove files older than about 7 days ([on a `daily` basis](http://bxr.su/OpenBSD/etc/crontab), as the name suggests).

---

***In summary***, you should first figure out what is the appropriate mapping between the web view of the filesystem and your filesystem.

Subsequently, if a prefix is found, just use a separate `location` for the assets, together with `alias`.

Else, figure out the paths for `try_files` to work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

I have find a very ugly solution until anyone find a better solution, here is what I have done :

- I have copied all the assets repository and copied it to my proxy server where nginx is.

Here is my new config :

```
location /portal/mysite/ {

    set $frontRoot /srv/data/apps/mysite-portal-stag/current/web;
    set $sfApp app.php; 

    root  /srv/data/apps/mysite-portal-stag/current/web;

    rewrite ^/portal/mysite/(.*)$ /$1 break;
    try_files $uri @sfFront;

}
location /portal/mysite/asset {
    root  /tmp/mysite/asset;
    rewrite ^/portal/mysite/asset/(.*)$ /$1 break;
}
location @sfFront {

    set $frontRootWeb /srv/data/apps/mysite-portal-stag/current/web;
    root  /srv/data/apps/mysite-portal-stag/current/web;

    fastcgi_pass myAdressWeb:myPort;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $frontRoot/$sfApp;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /portal/mysite/$sfApp;

}
```

And now it's working, all the js/css and pictures are found.

If anyone think about a "cleaner" answer, he is more than welcome to answer.